# AWS cognito make refresh_token optional

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am using this aws SDK "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider"

Is there any way to make refreh_token option at InitiateAuthCommand with some parameter

I want to pass remeber_me(boolean) in body and it will add refreh_token is it is true.
I don't want to add condition to remove refresh token after InitiateAuthCommand
I want it to not generate from aws-cognito.

```
export async function handler(event) {
  try {
    const { email, password } = JSON.parse(event.body);
    const srp = new SRPClient(CognitoCreds.userPoolId.split("_")[1]);
    const A = srp.calculateA();
    var loginResponse = await cognitoClient.send(
      new InitiateAuthCommand({
        AuthFlow: "USER_SRP_AUTH",
        ClientId: CognitoCreds.clientId,
        AuthParameters: {
          USERNAME: email,
          SRP_A: A,
        },
      })
    );
    if (loginResponse["$metadata"].httpStatusCode == 200) {
      const client = await DBclient(Client);
      const qry = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email ILIKE $1;";
      const res = await client.query(qry, [email]);
      let confirmed_status = res.rows[0]["userverified"];
      if (confirmed_status == false) {
        const updateQuery = `
              UPDATE users
              SET userverified = $2
              WHERE email = $1;
            `;

        await client.query(updateQuery, [email, true]);
        await client.end();
      }
      if (loginResponse.ChallengeName === "PASSWORD_VERIFIER") {
        const { SALT, SECRET_BLOCK, SRP_B, USER_ID_FOR_SRP } =
          loginResponse.ChallengeParameters;
        const hkdf = await srp.getPasswordAuthenticationKey(
          USER_ID_FOR_SRP,
          password,
          SRP_B,
          SALT
        );
        const dateNow = getNowString();
        const signatureString = await calculateSignature(
          hkdf,
          CognitoCreds.userPoolId.split("_")[1],
          USER_ID_FOR_SRP,
          SECRET_BLOCK,
          dateNow
        );

        const respondToChallengeResponse = await cognitoClient.send(
          new RespondToAuthChallengeCommand({
            ClientId: CognitoCreds.clientId,
            ChallengeName: "PASSWORD_VERIFIER",
            ChallengeResponses: {
              PASSWORD_CLAIM_SIGNATURE: signatureString,
              PASSWORD_CLAIM_SECRET_BLOCK: SECRET_BLOCK,
              TIMESTAMP: dateNow,
              USERNAME: USER_ID_FOR_SRP,
            },
          })
        );
        return sendResponse(200, respondToChallengeResponse);
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return sendResponse(500, err.message);
  }
}
```

Someone can help me with this?